# How to configure/display attribution sources in Firebase Analytics?

Tags: android, ios, firebase-analytics

All my attribution sources in Firebase Analytics for our Android and iOS apps are "(direct)", even though we have over 250k first_open events showing up since we migrated from Google Analytics to Firebase Analytics.

Is there something we need to configure for these to register properly, or am I not using the Console reporting correctly, or maybe something else?

I am expecting at least some basic sources like "organic search" to show up.

Comment: @David_Frahm did you already solve thdid you already solve this issue? Having the same...

Comment: @benrudhart have any of you guys solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase SDK library uses an app-instance identifier to identify a unique installation of the App.

When using the SDK, an app-instance identifier gets generated at the app level.

By default, the Firebase SDK collects identifiers for mobile devices (for example, Android Advertising ID and Advertising Identifier for iOS) and utilizes technologies similar to cookies.

On iOS, the SDK collects the Advertising Identifier if it is available. For IDFA to be available, a developer has to link in the following libraries:

libAdIdAccess.a
AdSupport.framework
If the Advertising Identifier is unavailable, the SDK collects the Vendor Identifier. If the Advertising Identifier becomes available after the Vendor Identifier was reported, the SDK stops collecting the Vendor Identifier.

By default, on Android the SDK collects the Advertising ID. If the Advertising ID is not collected, the device's hardware identifier, e.g., Android ID (SSAID), is collected instead. This alternative Android identifier cannot be reset.

source: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318039?hl=en

Comment: i think this answer is obsolete, due to changes on googles side. as i understand it:
Adding the dependencies in the firebase SDK for iOS is enough. Add the Pods: Firebase/Analytics and Firebase/DynamicLinks. The add the AdSupport framework to the app as well.
Then enable all the events like first_open, install, purchase etc. as conversions, then import those conversions into Google Ads. This will allow iOS attribution for Google Ads App campaigns only. No Search campaigns supported, and no Facebook campaigns or other third party networks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following dependencies to your app:

**1.a For iOS setup:**

Follow https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

And make sure you add the following Pods:

- Firebase/Analytics
- Firebase/DynamicLinks

**1.b For Android setup:**

Follow https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

If you use Option 1 in the tutorial link, make sure you enable Analytics in step 4.

If you use Option 2 in the tutorial link, make sure the following dependencies are included:

- Analytics
- Dynamic Links

**2. For iOS and Android, add the AdSupport framework to your App:**
https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/analytics-adsupport

Answer (score -1):

You can get this to work for your Android app by implementing Google Play Campaign attribution in your app.  Checkout the latest [instructions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-campaigns).  After adding this to your Android app, you can use UTM parameters on your links and the correct campaign attribution will show up in Firebase.

Comment: afaik, that's only for android. UTMs can't be retained for iOS app install campaigns. UTM parameters get lost as soon as an iOS device enters the apple appstore.