# How to set Firebase install source for ios app?

Tags: ios, firebase, iad, attribution

Information.
IOS app swift, firebase+analytics, bigquery integration, iAd (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iad)

Problem.
Most of installs are direct/none in firebase - so the same in analytics & bigquery. Main sources are google ads and apple ads. We can get apple ads source and campaign using iAd. But no info how to send this data to firebase (=how to set source for Firebase)

Question.

- Is it possible to manually set source/medium/campaign for Firebase? Can't find anything :(
- Any other tips how to get install source/medium/campaign and set it to Firebase?

Also, if we will use some tracker - appmetrica, appsflyer etc - there will be the same question - how to get source data from appsflyer and send it to Firebase

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you looked at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40472350/how-to-configure-display-attribution-sources-in-firebase-analytics)?

Comment: yes )
but question is not about attribution but about setting manually source medium , for example
firebase.set('source','blabla')

now we are trying to test setting params to campaign_details event, hope it helps

Comment: @mr.frog Posted an answer, Is it helpful?

Comment: thnx. it was helpful but I think it's not most correct solution

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [Firebase group conversation](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/daTGsNwpqjQ/m/sKlBlJ06AgAJ) :

> 1. Setup multiple user properties based on the info you have (like
>    source, medium, campaign, etc)
> 2. Combine 2 or more user properties to
>    make an audience
> 3. Filter your attribution report on the audience

Follow the whole conversation [here](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/daTGsNwpqjQ).

There is one [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup) about how to add firebase to your apple project and [another](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/installation-methods) on installation of firebase in your apple app.
For more information you can refer to the blog[5](https://www.monolithgrowth.com/blog-posts/how-to-set-up-app-analytics-for-android-and-ios-with-firebase), [medium post](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/firebase-traffic-source-attribution-guide-287d7de80d76) and [link](https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2018/12/14/how-campaign-attribution-works-google-analytics-firebase/) on how Campaign Attribution Works in Google Analytics for Firebase

Answer (score 0):

Okay. After researches and tests I have this view

(1) First of all - unfortunately look like firebase team doesn't make clear and working method of setting custom sources

(2) There is some possibility to send something directly to source/medium/campaign in Firebase, but it work unstable.
To do this you need
Get somewhere your Source/Medium/Campaign (for example from iAd)
send 'campaign_details' event with source/medium/campaign params

Also, as mentioned Divyani Yadav - You can just send this params anywhere to user_properties
And somehow work with this data (using bigquery or making audiences to make some analysis in Analytics), but this approach doesn't rewrite firebase initial source/medium/campaign params